# sunAngle() calculation in R giving wrong results

Tags: r, date, angles, altitude, position

I need to find the hourly sun angle (angle at which the sun strikes the Earth) for a particular position (latitude, longitude) for a given day in Belgium. I used sunAngle() from "oce" package for 31 July 2020. t is the hourly vector starting a 00:00:00 of that day until 00:00:00 of August 1.

```
lat = 50.879700
long = 4.700712
t0 <- as.POSIXct(paste("2020-07-31", "00:00:00"), tz="")
t <- seq(from=t0, to=t0+86400, by="60 min")
a <- sunAngle(t, lat, long)
```

The result is:

```
a[["altitude"]]
 [1] -60.225122 -49.174321 -36.305296 -22.665730  -8.661004   5.521092  19.768803
 [8]  33.983602  48.017946  61.503752  72.978661  75.957727  66.875621  53.924237
[15]  40.050031  25.882692  11.628080  -2.604935 -16.717790 -30.567994 -43.875928
[22] -55.964635 -64.970966 -66.929191 -60.402859`
```

However, this output can not be correct as it means that the sun rises at 4 am and sets at 5 pm, which is impossible for a summer day in Belgium.

Any idea of what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`sunAngle` args are longitude, latitude:

```
Usage:

     sunAngle(t, longitude = 0, latitude = 0, useRefraction = FALSE)
```

You called `sunAngle(t, lat, long)` which is the wrong way round, and R doesn't know what your variables are named, it matches them with the args of `sunAngle` by position.

Either name them, in which case you can do them any way round, or do them unnamed in the right order:

```
a <- data.frame(sunAngle(t, latitude=lat, longitude=long))
a <- data.frame(sunAngle(t, long, lat))
```

should work. I don't know personally know daylight hours in July in Belgium but this does return longer daylight hours (sunset ~19:30 UTC?)

Comment: Indeed, I inverted the latitude and longitude, by placing them in the right order it worked! tz = "" refers to the local timezone of your computer, as I am in Belgium it gives me the right output (sunset 22h) but tz ="CEST" should be used if the code is ran from another time zone. Thank you!